# How can I deploy code via Capistrano 3 using a different username on the server from the command line?

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I recently upgraded to Capistrano 2.x to 3.x and the process was fairly straightforward. But what bugs me is the loss of command line functionality that used to exist in Capistrano 2.x. Specifically, if I wanted to deploy to a remote server via a different user than my system’s current logged in user I could run a command like this:

```
cap -s user=remote_user staging deploy
```

Capistrano 3.x allows one to set a specific user in the deployment scripts itself via a configuration setting like this; note the `user:` option:

```
server 'example.com', user: 'remote_user', roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
```

Which is very nice! But I do system administration on setups where multiple users—not just a generic `deploy` user—can deploy code that is managed by group permissions on the server. Meaning users, `linus`, `snoopy` and `lucy` and all work on the same code and then deploy under their own unique username and everything works. And no, switching this setup to use a generic `deploy` is not an easy option for now to say the least. The codebase is fairly straightforward PHP code—from a deployment standpoint—and Capistrano helps simplify the deployment workflow.

I have no desire to roll back to Capistrano 2.x. So how can I keep these users and Capistrano scripts in line with Capistrano 3.x settings but still allow everyone to independently deploy code via their own individual user accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I keep these users and Capistrano scripts in line with
>   Capistrano 3.x settings but still allow users to independently deploy
>   code via their own individual user accounts?

While not as clean as the Capistrano 2.x method of using `-s user=remote_user`, a similar goal of setting custom usernames can be achieved by using environment variables in Capistrano 3.x. This has been tested and works well in Capistrano 3.4.0.

The first thing one has to do is adjust their server settings to allow for an environment variable. So the `server` line that reads like this above:

```
server 'example.com', user: 'remote_user', roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
```

Now gets changed to add an `ENV["CAP_USER"]` variable like this:

```
server 'example.com', user: ENV["CAP_USER"] || 'remote_user', roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
```

The logic basically boils down to: If `ENV["CAP_USER"]` is set, use that. If not, just use `remote_user`.

And now to take advantage of that from the command line, one would just deploy like this:

```
export CAP_USER=remote_user && cap staging deploy
```

Note the `export CAP_USER=remote_user` is what sets the environment variable named `CAP_USER` which then gets accessed as `ENV["CAP_USER"]` in the Capistrano 3.x script. The `&&` is just a Bash command to concatenate that command to the next `cap staging deploy`.

If one wanted to, one could just adjust their `~/.bash_profile` to permanently set the `CAP_USER` to `remote_user` so the basic `cap staging deploy` can be used as-is without having to remember the syntax of a compound command.